# javascript-how can I see result of every condition in one if statement By Debugging in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, if-statement, debugging, multiple-conditions

I Have some javascript code that has if statements with multiple conditions .

I want to see which one is true or false in chrome debugging.

for example:

```
if(a.value=='' || (document.getElementById('test') && document.getElementById('test').value==='') || myfom_upload.value==='' || document.forms['test_form']['name'].value==='' || document.getElementById('test_id').value==='' )
{
 //some codes.
}
```

**I want to see result of :**

`(a.value=='')`====>(true or false)?

`(document.getElementById('test'))`  ====>(true or false)?

`document.getElementById('test')` ====>(true or false)?

`(document.getElementById('test').value==='')` ====> (true or false)?

`(myfom_upload.value==='')`====>(true or false)?

`document.forms['test_form']['name'].value===''` ====>(true or false)?

`document.getElementById('test_id').value===''` ====>(true or false)?

How can I see result of every condition in one if statement By Debugging in Chrome?

Is there anyway in console.log or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Place your breakpoint on the line with the if condition
2. Trigger the event that executes the code.
3. When the execution pauses at the breakpoint, drag your cursor over to select `a.value` and hover over the selected text. You'll be able to see the value.
4. Repeat

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have an update in my question. doesnt work this way for `document.forms['test_form']['name'].value===''` .

Comment: Even doesnt work for `document.getElementById('test_id').value` or `document.getElementsByClassName('test_classname').value`

Comment: That's too complex for chrome to understand on the fly. If you want to view its value, store it in a variable before you actually use it like:
`const x = document.getElementsByClassName('test_classname').value`

Then in your condition say if (x == 'something'), use the method of highlighting like I mentioned earlier.

Comment: but when this javascript can run and has value by / in chrome, so chrome can show detail in debugging